Using numpy to sort datetime lists
I'm reading in a text file whose output looks like this:
['XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:22:00  2024/319 12:31:03   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:22:00  2024/319 12:31:03   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:55:03  2024/319 13:17:38   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:55:03  2024/319 13:17:38   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 14:33:50  2024/319 14:45:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 14:33:50  2024/319 14:45:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_10      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 19:47:00  2024/319 20:08:37   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:22:00  2024/319 12:31:03   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:22:00  2024/319 12:31:03   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:55:03  2024/319 13:16:47   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:55:03  2024/319 13:16:47   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 14:33:50  2024/319 14:45:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 14:33:50  2024/319 14:45:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_11      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 19:47:00  2024/319 20:07:47   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 19:47:00  2024/319 20:13:11   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 19:47:00  2024/319 20:13:11   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 21:29:03  2024/319 22:28:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 21:29:03  2024/319 22:28:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/320 01:32:00  2024/320 01:54:06   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/320 01:32:00  2024/320 01:54:06   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_12      SATLIT        9.900   2024/320 02:37:13  2024/320 02:54:27   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 11:44:00  2024/319 12:00:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 11:44:00  2024/319 12:00:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:55:03  2024/319 13:41:19   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 12:55:03  2024/319 13:41:19   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 15:05:00  2024/319 15:11:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 15:05:00  2024/319 15:11:00   TR2    # SOH'
 'XXXX_6       SATLIT        9.900   2024/319 18:32:00  2024/319 19:02:03   TR2    # SOH']

How do I sort this array using np using the first time slots? Columns 4 and 5.
searchfile = open('SATLIT_schedule.txt')

d = np.array(searchfile.readlines())
sortd = np.sort(d, 3)
print sortd


As loaded this array is 1d, with a long string in each element.  There are no columns.  Using np.loadtxt I imagine it would produce a structured array, with dates and times in the 4-7 the columns.  However getting the dtype for '2024/319' values could be tricky - is that a fraction or a 'date' (year/days-in-year')?  Do you need to sort the following column, which appears to be a time?  Massaging the data before sorting could be a major task.

Unless you give us an idea what 2024/320 is, it would be little lengthy to determine the right dtype.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Well, I assume the dates you have specified are in the format YYYY/DDD (Column 4) HH:MM:SS (Column 5). Here is a solution I wrote using numpy and pandas:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = np.genfromtxt("SATLIT_schedule.txt", dtype=str)
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

You can then concatenate the HH:MM:SS columns to their corresponding YYYY/DDD columns
df.loc[:, 3] = df.loc[:, 3] + "/" + df.loc[:, 4]
df.loc[:, 5] = df.loc[:, 5] + "/" + df.loc[:, 6]

Of course then we can get rid of the HH:MM:SS columns since they have already been concatenated to their corresponding YYYY/DDD columns
df.drop(4, axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop(6, axis=1, inplace=True)

We can actually just sort the column of the datetimes lexographically and it will come out sorted by date since the format (YYYY/DDD/HH:MM:SS) is sorted by order or importance.
df.sort_values(3, axis=0, ascending=False)

We then get the final sorted pandas Dataframe:
print(df)

Sorted dataframe

A little sidenote, converting pandas DataFrames (df) into ndarrays can be done using df.to_numpy()
